# What are permissions that my lambda function need to retrieve secrets from AWS Secrets Manager

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

What are permissions that my lambda function need to be able to retrieve secrets from AWS Secrets Manager and change it also ?

Answer (score 1):

You need the `secretsmanager:GetSecretValue` policy to retrieve secrets and the `secretsmanager:UpdateSecret` policy to update secrets.

Note that if you are using a customer-managed AWS KMS key for encryption you will also need some KMS permissions:

- `kms:Decrypt` for retrieving the secret.
- `kms:Decrypt` and `kms:GenerateDataKey` for updating the secret.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/secretsmanager/get-secret-value.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/secretsmanager/update-secret.html

Comment: Yep; Thanks I'm using those polices but I'm not able to access the secret IN MAY CASE I'M USING SPECIFIC VPC ones i delete the VPC my Lambda function work correctly but i need to be able to use it with specific VPC so if you have any idea about the issue i get with the usage of specific VPC i'll appreciate if you share it with me

Comment: @learn.amzn21 so you need to run the Lambda on a specific VPC, is that correct? Can you also share the error from the Lambda logs?

Comment: {
  "errorMessage": "2021-05-21T08:54:56.954Z 103aa5dd-675b-4a61-876e-279c64fc1239 Task timed out after 25.03 seconds"
}

Comment: START RequestId: 103aa5dd-675b-4a61-876e-279c64fc1239 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 103aa5dd-675b-4a61-876e-279c64fc1239
REPORT RequestId: 103aa5dd-675b-4a61-876e-279c64fc1239 Duration: 25025.19 ms Billed Duration: 25000 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 69 MB Init Duration: 220.53 ms 
2021-05-21T08:54:56.954Z 103aa5dd-675b-4a61-876e-279c64fc1239 Task timed out after 25.03 seconds

Comment: i try to change timeout i give more time it's not the problem also the problem is that i'm not able to access the secret but wen i run same code in Lambda function without specify the VPC it work correctly. So i'm not sure if i need to add more permissions ??

Comment: Does the subnet where the Lambda is running have access to the internet? This is likely to be a network issue. Check the security group outbound rules and the subnet network configuration and make sure you have access to the AWS Secrets endpoint. As a quick turnaround, you can launch an EC2 instance with the same subnet and security group as the Lambda function and then test the connectivity to the Secrets Manager using the AWS CLI.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Lambda functions provided by AWS, then (as described in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotating-secrets-required-permissions.html)) you will need: DescribeSecret, GetSecretValue, PutSecretValue, UpdateSecretVersionStage and GetRandomPassword. If you are using a Custom KMS Key (CMK) you will also need Decrypt and GenerateDataKey permissions for that CMK (both in the Lambda policy and in the KMS key policy).

If you are seeing Task timed out errors, it is likely your Lambda can not access either the secrets manager endpoint (try using a [VPC endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoint-overview.html)), or the [Lambda can not connect to the DB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotating-secrets.html) (check security group settings).